# How to create controlled CPU load on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, cpu

I'd like to know how to generate a controlled CPU load on Linux using shell or python script. By controlled load I mean creating a process that consumes a specified amount of CPU cycles (e.g., 20% of available CPU cycles).

I wrote a python script that does some dummy computation like generating N random integers and sort them using the built-in sort function. I used "time" utility in Linux to compute the User and Kernel time consumed by the process. But I am not sure how to compute the CPU utilization of the specific process from CPU time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to to use time.sleep() and play around with how long to sleep in between calculations?